# Relocate menu bar item with applescript?

Tags: applescript, menu-bar

Suppose that I want to move a menu bar item to the right. Then I do command + drag and drop.

Now, is there a way to do it with applescript? In particular, this is useful when some icons on the bar gets hidden. Moving them to the right can make them reappear.